# What Is The Use Of map_meta_cap Filter?

Tags: customization, custom-post-types

What is the use of [`map_meta_cap`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap) filter? This filter is not documented anywhere. I have an unclear idea of what it could be:

Used to map the permissions of the user to operations on posts.

What exactly is it meant for? If possible please give some sample code example of its right usage.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This filter allows you to extend [the `map_meta_cap()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L780). This function [is called by `WP_User->has_cap()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L728) to convert a *meta capability* to one or more *primitive capabilities*.

For example, you want to know whether the current user should be allowed to edit the current post, [the `edit_post` meta capability](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L892). This depends on some factors: is the user the author of the post? Is the post already published? Is the post marked as private? The primitive capabilities are `edit_posts`, `edit_published_posts`, `edit_others_posts` and `edit_private_posts`: you can assign these to [user roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). `map_meta_cap()` checks the author and status of the post and returns the correct set of *primitive capabilities* this user must have to allow editing of the post (if the post is written by someone else and published, it would return `array('edit_others_posts', 'edit_published_posts')`, so the user must have both capabilities to continue).

Adding this idea of *meta capabilities* and *primitive capabilities* allows you to keep the base `WP_User` class free from knowledge of posts and post statuses and whatever, and just focus on capabilities. The actual conversion is in an external function, `map_meta_cap()`.

[The filter `map_meta_cap`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L1047) allows you to extend the functionality, for example when using custom posts. I believe basic support is provided if you set the `capabilities` argument of [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), but the mentioned article by [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types) and [Prospress plugin](http://github.com/Prospress/Prospress/blob/master/pp-posts/pp-capabilities.php) provide complete examples of this. But you can customize it to completely turn the capabilities system over, if you desire.

Answer (score 8):

This filter can be used to map meta capabilities for custom post types. There is a good code sample in this article:

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types

Answer (score 2):

This is filter of function `map_meta_cap()`. From description this function seems to write out general capability (*can_do_stuff*) passed into more specific (if post's author then *can_do_this_stuff* and *can_do_that_stuff_also*), checking various conditions if needed.

Unfortunately it is not documented in Codex and I can't find a single direct call of this function in WP 3.0.1 source.

Had you encountered usage of this function or want to use it for something? I assume since it doesn't seem to be used, there are probably newer and better ways for this functionality.

Comment: This plug-in author seems to be using it:

http://github.com/Prospress/Prospress/blob/master/pp-posts/pp-capabilities.php