# What's the difference between Role and Meta capabilities; When to use map_meta_cap() filter

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I'm getting very confused about the following things:

1. difference between Role and Meta capabilities,
2. difference between Meta and Primitive capabilities,
3. when to use `map_meta_cap()` filter.

There were lots of situations, where I add WP existing or custom capabilities to either WP existing or custom roles, expecting it to work out of the box and most of the times it doesn't.

I see that people mention about `map_meta_cap()` filter, but I can't find a good explanation what it actually does and when do I have to use it and when capabilities will work out of the box.

I hope that makes sense.

I would hugely appreciate explanations or links to resources that explain this well.

Thanks,
Dasha

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Is The Use Of map\_meta\_cap Filter?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-use-of-map-meta-cap-filter)

Comment: [This post by Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types) was ultimately the source of information I benefited most from.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

> difference between Role and Meta capabilities

That would be better to ask the compare `Role` with `Capabilities`, not just `Meta capabilities`, but as a simple answer:

A `Role` defines a set of tasks a user assigned the role is allowed to perform.

`Capabilities` are assigned to `Roles`

> difference between Meta and Primitive capabilities?

**Meta capabilities**

`edit_post`, `read_post`, and `delete_post` are said to be `Meta Capabilities` because they depend on the context, for example the post being edited/read/deleted. That makes no sense if you say, some user has `edit_post` capability, because somebody will ask you: **she/he can edit which post?**

**Primitive capabilities**

These are capabilities like `edit_posts` which do not depend on any context, and are intrinsic to the user. If somebody has `edit_posts` capabality, she/he can edit posts.

> when to use map_meta_cap() filter?

When you register new **post type** using [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
, you have an option to use for `capability_type` which says, what are the capabilities, similar to? There you may just say `post`, meaning that you capabilities are similar to that of `post` post type.

Bu if you need more customization, you may say `book` or `array( 'book', 'books' )` (the same), for example, to have the following capabilities:

```
capabilities' => array(
  'edit_post'          => 'edit_book', 
  'read_post'          => 'read_book', 
  'delete_post'        => 'delete_book', 
  'edit_posts'         => 'edit_books', 
  'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_others_books', 
  'publish_posts'      => 'publish_books',       
  'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_books', 
  'create_posts'       => 'edit_books', 
)
```

When using `capability_type` as an array, e.g. array('story', 'stories') the first element will be used for the singular capabilities and the second array element for the plural capabilities.

The `map_meta_cap()` function is called by `WP_User->has_cap()` to convert a meta capability to one or more primitive capabilities.

There is also a `map_meta_cap` parameter in `register_post_type`, which does the same thing,at the post_type registration.

Comment: `...If somebody has edit_posts capabality, she/he can edit posts...` but which/whose posts?