# How to allow editor to edit privacy page / settings only?

Tags: user-roles, privacy, privileges

In my WordPress installation `(4.9.8.)` the editor role isn't allowed to edit the privacy page.

It would work with following in my `functions.php`:

```
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'manage_privacy_options', true );
$role_object->add_cap( 'manage_options' ); // this needs to be active in order that before cap works
```

But now the editor has lot more rights than just editing the privacy page.

Is there another way to `grant access to the editor user role` with some lines of PHP code?

---

As a workaround I make usage of this Plugin now:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-privacy-options/

Another kind of workaround is just to choose no privacy page in the privacy settings.

Comment: perhaps this can be of help? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/4-9-6-new-privacy-capability/

Comment: @George, yes, i saw that page too. don't know what's wrong with my code. tested it with two different quite plain WP installations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Editing the privacy policy page is restricted to `manage_privacy_options` as pointed out in a comment in the WordPress core file `wp-includes/capabilities.php`:

```
/*
 * Setting the privacy policy page requires `manage_privacy_options`,
 * so editing it should require that too.
 */
if ( (int) get_option( 'wp_page_for_privacy_policy' ) === $post->ID ) {
  $caps = array_merge( $caps, map_meta_cap( 'manage_privacy_options', $user_id ) );
}
```

To allow users <strike>with the roles `editor` and `administrator`</strike> who can edit pages (in single and also multisite instances) to edit and delete the privacy policy page one has to overwrite the `$caps` array:

```
add_action('map_meta_cap', 'custom_manage_privacy_options', 1, 4);
function custom_manage_privacy_options($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args)
{
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $caps;

  if ('manage_privacy_options' === $cap) {
    $manage_name = is_multisite() ? 'manage_network' : 'manage_options';
    $caps = array_diff($caps, [ $manage_name ]);
  }
  return $caps;
}
```

Update: Allow users with the role `editor` or `administrator` to edit and delete the privacy policy page (which is not possible per default in multisite instances):

```
add_action('map_meta_cap', 'custom_manage_privacy_options', 1, 4);
function custom_manage_privacy_options($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args)
{
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) return $caps;

  $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
  if (array_intersect(['editor', 'administrator'], $user_meta->roles)) {
    if ('manage_privacy_options' === $cap) {
      $manage_name = is_multisite() ? 'manage_network' : 'manage_options';
      $caps = array_diff($caps, [ $manage_name ]);
    }
  }
  return $caps;
}
```

Comment: oh looks very clever.. 1. does `$caps = array_diff($caps, [ $manage_name ]);` restrict all other cap's of `manage_options `? and just allow to edit the privacy options? 2. the `administrator ` would not need this really, as this cap already in, or?

Comment: @AndréKelling 1. The hook `map_meta_cap` is working on a per-post basis. No other post has the restriction `manage_privacy_options` so it should be fine to remove it. More information [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2586/32946).
2. In WordPress multisite environments only super-administrators are allowed to edit the privacy policy page. As you mentioned, this is not relevant for single page installations.

Comment: @AndréKelling Do you have any further questions regarding my answer? If not, please accept the answer to mark this question as solved :)

Comment: no sorry, couldn't find the time to check this. will do immediately!

Comment: This works pretty fine but wouldn't it be better to check the users role additionally … this should affect this cap for all user doesn't it?

Comment: @GDY Good point. I assumed that only editors and administrators can edit pages. I added the check of the user role to my answer.

Comment: Actually the question asks for the editor role (which cant edit the privacy page in regular installations) so it should cover editors and admins.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer one more time. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: awesome one ! thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. For those wanting to enable WooCommerce Shop Managers to the list allowed to edit privacy add "shop_manager" to the array_intersect  in the second example.

Comment: I know `add_action` is an alias for the `add_filter`, but since the `map_meta_cap` filter is defined using `apply_filters`, I think you should replace `add_action()` with `add_filter()` for brevity

Comment: This code causes a fatal error (`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_intersect(): Argument #2 must be of type array, null given ...snip... /wp-admin/user-new.php(195): edit_user()`) when creating a new user account. It seems that the user can be null. I've added an extra line of checks after the `get_userdata()` call which wraps it like this: `if ($user_meta && isset($user_meta->roles) && is_array($user_meta->roles)) { }`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Sven for the nice workaround, it works well but I had an issue when the user is not yet logged_in, the map_meta_cap action is fired anyway, which resulted on a "502 bad getaway" error. I added a `is_user_logged_in()` test before like so :

```
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    add_action('map_meta_cap', 'custom_manage_privacy_options', 1, 4);
}
```

Maybe it's my server configuration (nginx) that results on this bug, but if someone get the same error, here is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answer did the trick. However, this line:

```
if (array_intersect(['editor', 'administrator'], $user_meta->roles)) {
```

Was generating this error:

```
array_intersect(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given in
```

So I tweaked the code a bit to ensure that both values were valid arrays (full code):

```
add_action('map_meta_cap', 'custom_manage_privacy_options', 1, 4);
function custom_manage_privacy_options($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args) {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) return $caps;

$target_roles = array('editor', 'administrator');
$user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_roles = ( array ) $user_meta->roles;

if ( array_intersect($target_roles, $user_roles) ) {
    if ('manage_privacy_options' === $cap) {
        $manage_name = is_multisite() ? 'manage_network' : 'manage_options';
        $caps = array_diff($caps, [ $manage_name ]);
    }
}

return $caps;
}
```

Comment: I don't see what you've changed. If $user_meta->roles is null you're still passing null to array_intersect here.

Comment: As we're making sure that the user is logged in first, the $user_meta->roles could never null? I thought that the problem was due to using $user_meta->roles directly on the array_intersect, so I saved that as a variable first. I'm no longer getting any error messages so it seems like that fixed the issue.

Comment: Casting $user_meta->roles as an array is definitely not the best way. Just check if $user_meta is set.